# How exactly can a get be forced

Tags: halacha, divorce

Under what rules can a get be forced and still be kosher? There seems to be contradiction. On the one hand, a get 'meusa' is posul; on the other hand, bais din can force him.

Comment: ger, welcome to Mi Yodeya! This question would be a great deal stronger if you could [edit] in the bases for your understanding of the assumptions of this question, namely " a get 'meusa' is posul" and "bais din can force him." Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: here is one discussion which covers the notion of free will in issuing a get http://www.jlaw.com/Articles/getart3.html

Answer (score 5):

[Here](http://5tjt.com/the-cattle-prod-get-a-halachic-analysis/) is a treatment of the subject. Basically it comes down to three views:

1) If the Torah requires the get, his real desire is to give it, and the coercing removes the Yetzer Hara's objection, which is not him.

2) It is like someone forced to sell something under duress where they get the payment. Either the "seller" (the husband) loses nothing in the transaction, or he even gains the Mitzvah. Such a transaction, even when forced, is ultimately valid. In other words, the "meusa" has to be relevant to the interests of the husband. If he is just being obstinate, that can't hold the wife as an aguna.

3) Since the marriage was on condition of the Chachamim's agreement (according to the Laws of Moshe and Yisroel - Yisroel being the Chachamim), here the Chachamim just invalidate the marriage. The forced get is simply technique for invoking their rejection of the marriage. The get doesn't accomplish its Torah purpose.

Please see [the article](http://5tjt.com/the-cattle-prod-get-a-halachic-analysis/) for more in-depth discussion of the sources. The different opinions create different circumstances under which force would create a valid divorce.

Comment: A slight editorial: Regardless, the recent write up in the news (which I assume prompted the question) struck me as most problematic around the issue of essentially buying (bribing) the "Beis Din" for a result, a result where people involved gain financially.

Comment: Are you sure about #3? Doesn't that make it an annulment, not a divorce?

Comment: @SethJ, yes it does. To quote the article: "In the cases of a forced get in the Mishna, the Radbaz explains, the Rabbis essentially revoked the marriage from the onset."

Comment: So what function does the actual Get itself serve?

Comment: So according to #3, can we be matir Mamzeirim this way (if the husband shows up, force him to give a get)?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, not really, as they would probably be Mamzerim MeDerabbanan anyway, and regardless, his showing up after the wife improperly remarried is not one of the circumstances that allows a forced Get.