# Why is it often Claimed a Forced Get is Invalid?

Tags: divorce, beit-din-court

I've read that part of the problem of agunot ( women who are refused a divorce ) is that if we force the man to give a get then the get is invalidated, and thus Beitai Din in Israel refrain from using force.

However, that [is not strictly true](http://www.jlaw.com/Articles/getart3.html):

> A most basic rule in Hilchot Gittin is that a Get must be given (and received by the wife, post-Cherem d'Rabbeinu Gershom) of one's own free will. (Rambam, Gerushin 1:1,2) If the husband is coerced, the Get is invalid. (Rambam, Hilchot Gerushin, 220[*sic*]) The oft-quoted dictum kofin osoh ad sheyomar rotzeh ani -- "we coerce him until he states 'I want to"' -- applies only in cases when (a) specific grounds for that verdict exist, (b) the Bet Din renders a verdict of kofin (we force him), and (c) the coercion is carried out by the Bet Din or others implementing its verdict.

We see that a Beit Din has the authority to coerce the man to give the get, and we can see from Rambam in [הלכות אישות פרק טו, ב](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/4115.htm#8) regarding a marriage without children for ten years that the Beit Din physically beats the husband till he gives a divorce (or takes a second wife).

In light of that, I don't understand why it seems that Batai Din refuse to use force in cases where the husband uses the refusal of a get as a means of blackmailing his wife, and where the claim of the Get being invalidated by the use of force comes from.

Comment: Your title and body don't exactly match up. Could you [edit] to clarify which one you mean?

Comment: @Scimonster I edited the title and the last paragraph, does that make it clearer?

Comment: They could also retroactively nullify the marriage outright, that occurs in gittin as well.

Comment: @BabySeal Accd to many those are the same http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43738/759

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31593/how-exactly-can-a-get-be-forced

Answer (score 4):

This one's pretty straightforward -- forcing a Get only works in situations when halacha says beis din can do so. The Talmud gives examples of abusive behavior or intolerable medical conditions; but if they're just annoyed with each other's personalities, we don't have a halacha that says beis din can use coercion.

Hence the beis din has to make a tricky call, "is this a situation that allows coercion?" If they rule "no coercion" when it should be used, she could be stuck; but if they rule "yes coercion" when it shouldn't, then the Get would be invalid. But many batei din can be a bit gun-shy about making this ruling.

Rambam's opinion is that if she simply says "I get sick at the thought of having relations with him", that's enough to warrant coercion, but others (e.g. the Rosh) disagree.

Comment: So why can't they rely on the Rambam's ruling on this matter, especially since the men in most of these case clearly intend to divorce the woman and are willing to do so, and are only withholding the get in order to blackmail the woman financially, i.e. not to pay the ketubah or even worse to get the woman to pay them a large sum for the get, or other similar blackmail.

Comment: Also, what are the list of things for which Beit Din can use coercion according to various authorities.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes it is often not that simple. Many publicized stories only paint the woman's side of things

Comment: @BabySeal I wouldn't say "often". Maybe "sometimes". Not that it shouldn't be accounted for.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes Because maybe we don't rule that way?

Comment: @DoubleAA "Because maybe we don't rule that way" is not a reason, any more than "because" would be a reason.  It's like saying we don't do it because we don't do it.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes Some forms of coercion are probably not legal according to secular law. That said, there are certain chassidic communities where physical violence is sometimes used to "persuade" the husband to give a get.

Comment: @Fred In the state of Israel the secular law allows the beit din to use an escalating set of measures, such as revoking his passport, drivers license, imprisoning him, and putting him in solitary confinement in prison for an unlimited amount of time.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes yes the law has given the beit din some very nice tools -- but you need a good beit din that can get a good grasp of the situation and not be afraid to pasken that "coercion" is justified.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes You asked why not rely on the Rambam and I explained it's because we rule against him. That's an excellent answer. I don't know what else you want someone to possibly say.

Comment: @DoubleAA The reasoning behind why some / most Talmidai Chachmim disagree with him.

Comment: Note that there is a difference between a "coerced get" (in which he says he does not want to give it) and using force to make him say *I want to*