# Non-Jewish court imposing payments until a Jewish divorce is given

Tags: divorce

[This recent news article](https://www.thejc.com/news/uk-news/businessman-loses-appeal-to-avoid-having-to-pay-maintenance-until-he-gives-a-get-1.487843) discusses a Jewish man who was ordered by a non-Jewish court to pay maintenance to his wife until he grants her a *get* (Jewish divorce document).

The man claimed in court that if he were to grant a *get* under the terms of this ruling, the *get* would in fact be invalid, as it would have been given under compulsion.

The judge rejected this argument. But what do *halachic* sources say?

**If a non-Jewish court imposes payments until a *get* is given, would that invalidate a subsequently granted *get*? Under what circumstances is a 'compelled *get*' valid or invalid? What exactly are the parameters that define a 'compelled *get*'?**

Ideally, I would like as comprehensive an answer as possible, but answers discussing specific scenarios are of course welcome. I would be particularly interested in answers addressing the case described in the linked article, where there does not seem to have been any involvement of a Beit Din (Jewish court) in the process.

Comment: The classic case is Shulchan Arukh EH 134:4 and :9. How to apply that to your case, which is something classical authorities probably never would have dreamed of, is not entirely obvious. It's a very difficult Halakhic question (unlike the mistaken and oversimplified presentation below)

Answer (score 2):

In some prenuptial agreements (e.g., the [RCA](https://www.rabbis.org/forms/Halachic%20Prenuptial%20Arbitration%20Agreement.pdf)) my understanding is that the parties agree to a certain monetary penalty and agree it can be enforced through civil courts (see VII).

An alternative scenario would be if the husband refused (*siruv*) to appear in front of a *beit din* which then allowed the wife to pursue penalties in civil court.

In both of these cases, a penalty would be allowed by the *Beit Din* and I can't imagine that they would allow it if it makes the *get* invalid.

But the strongest argument might come from the famous Rambam ([Gerushin 2:20](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/957707/jewish/Gerushin-Chapter-Two.htm)) writing one can penalize (beat) a man for failing to divorce his wife, and that it is not called forcing him to divorce, because every man wants to do the right thing (divorce) and we are just helping him fight his *yetzer hara*.

> When a man whom the law requires to be compelled to divorce his wife
>   does not desire to divorce her, the court should have him beaten until
>   he consents, at which time they should have a get written. The get is
>   acceptable. This applies at all times and in all places.
>
> [...]
>
> Why is this get not void? For he is being compelled - either by Jews
>   or by gentiles - [to divorce] against his will [and a get must be
>   given voluntarily].
>
> Because the concept of being compelled against one's will applies only
>   when speaking about a person who is being compelled and forced to do
>   something that the Torah does not obligate him to do - e.g., a person
>   who was beaten until he consented to a sale, or to give a present. If,
>   however, a person's evil inclination presses him to negate [the
>   observance of] a mitzvah or to commit a transgression, and he was
>   beaten until he performed the action he was obligated to perform, or
>   he dissociated himself from the forbidden action, he is not considered
>   to have been forced against his will. On the contrary, it is he
>   himself who is forcing [his own conduct to become debased].

Comment: Regarding your first point, maybe it's different if a beit din is allowing the involvement of civil courts?

Comment: Regarding Rambam, that only applies where he is obligated to issue a divorce according to *halacha*. What if that is not the case?

Comment: Your question was whether a divorce following court-imposed penalties would be valid? I tried to show it could be, if either there was a prenuptial agreement, if the *beit din* allowed the woman to proceed in civil court, or if the *beit din* compels the man to divorce. There are of course other cases but the three scenarios above are all quite possible

Comment: Got it, thanks. I'd love to see a more comprehensive answer addressing the issue more broadly, and especially focusing on what exactly counts as compulsion in giving a *get* (*get me'useh*) but this is a great start. Thanks again

Comment: I've added a paragraph to tighten the focus of the question, but I don't think it invalidates your answer

Comment: No problem - you did well - thanks

Comment: Your understanding of the RCA prenup is entirely mistaken.

Comment: Note many authorities disagree with that Rambam. It's famous so fun to quote, but probably not actually accepted. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/31595/759

Comment: I don't understand your second case. What is the basis there?

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't know what you mean regarding "entirely mistaken" - the prenup is described at https://www.ou.org/life/relationships/ending-agunah-problem-as-we-know-it-shlomo-wiessmann/ and I don't see how my summary is incorrect

Comment: @mbloch it's not a penalty, chas veshalom. The husband quantifies how to pay food anytime she wants the whole marriage. You are entirely mistaken. This is a very dangerous answer.